# Inserting Computer Log Record System In Access through VB source code

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm doing practical in my college right now. Since I'm in Malaysia, I have created most of textbox name in Malay. My lecturer wants me to create a computer log record system in VB & save it in Access DB through VB source code. I have created 5 VB design forms and have created successfully Form 1 & 2. I'm currently stuck in Form 3 which is a person enter his log record and save it in database.I have created the source code but when I enter the data in Form 3 it shows error like this **C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\bin\Debug\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\Rekod Penggunaaan Lab.accdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.** Form 1 is for Admin Login which has Username & Password. Form 2 goes for Staff Log and Student Log. I hope anyone there could guide me in completing my project. Just asking guidance while trying my level best to finish my project. I'm also adding Form 3 sample images.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQeXZ.jpg)

Comment: `I have created the source code`. So where is the code?
Please show what you have tried and state which part you are having problem with. What you are asking now is basically asking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: If you have blanks in the dbpath you have to surround it by double quotes `"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\bin\Debug\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\Rekod Penggunaaan Lab.accdb"` Follow @Student 's advice and show the code, if this is not the issue or give it to community at beginning next time!

Comment: Thanks for the reply & advice BitAccesser but what is Student's Advice anyway? I have entered the double quote just like you said but the error showed InvalidOperationException was unhandled. Additional Information: Not allowed to change the ConnectionString property. The connection's current state is open. Im not sure though how to insert data through VB Form to Access DB. Hope you can guide me....I'm have copy paste the image and inserting here for every1 view...

Comment: Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form3

    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()

    End Sub

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Sistem Rekod Penggunaan Lab\Rekod Penggunaan Lab.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert Into STAFF LOG([NAMA], [NO ID], [LAB], [KOD SUBJEK], [MASA MASUK], [MASA KELUAR]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Comment: Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NAMA", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NO ID", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("KOD SUBJEK", CType(ComboBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LAB", CType(ComboBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MASA MASUK", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MASA MASUK", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))

Comment: Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)